# Freebasic install for Raspberry Pi problem

Tags: pi, freebasic

I am looking to install Freebasic on a Raspberry Pi. I have already looked at the Freebasic forum - but it seems from a lot of posts that others have found that following the steps shown no longer end up working.

Other Pi forums have said that a working installation can be difficult to achieve.

I am trying to find a way to get the freebasic compiler running on an otherwise virgin installation, starting from Noobs.

At first I thought it was too difficult for me, but even some serious pi-enthusiasts who were going to help me have ended up stumped.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://scruss.com/blog/2015/03/25/running-freebasic-on-raspberry-pi/) has a step by step that can be considered simple, as long as attention is paid to the directories and first step, installing some necessary packages.

I followed steps 1 through 5 and installed it on my Raspberry.
From what is reported there, "part of the problem is that FreeBASIC is written primarily in FreeBASIC, so you need a working compiler to initialize the latest version".

Therefore, you need to install an "old version" (step #2), clone the latest version and compile it with the old version (step #3). Uninstall old version (step #4) and install new version (step #5).

In step #3 I used the `make -j4` command. I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

In my case, I used [fbc_linux_armv6_rpi_0365_2020-01-12.zip](http://users.freebasic-portal.de/stw/builds/linux-armv6-rpi/fbc_linux_armv6_rpi_0365_2020-01-12.zip) as "old version". I tested the installation by compiling and running a program and it was OK, working perfectly.